# Is comparing DateTime saved accross different systems a Bad idea?

Tags: c#, windows, datetime

In one of my code I am doing so that, there is a process running different systems and I save some data to database with that I saved field DateTime with value DateTime.UtcNow (C#) , and then one of the systems I collect all the data from different systems then order it by DateTime field, to order the data has been saved.

In this I also check if SystemA written data DateTime field is greater than SystemB written data DateTime field and then which ever data is latest I save that.

Now, I would like to know whether this kind of DateTime comparision from different systems is a bad idea?

**I am not considering for scenarios where the system clock are very wrong.**

Comment: This is opinion based.

Comment: Systems should have close enough to reality date & time... Most, if not all, modern operative systems do have NTP clients incorporated. That would also help a lot for tracing purposes if you have to check different systems' data if things go south.

Comment: DateTime objects are stored as a number in UTC time so computers in different time zones will always get same results.Net Library will automatically take the Timezone of PC as default when Parsing a string to DateTime, or when outputting DateTime to string.So when inputting a DateTime the string input should contain a timezone if different from local time.Microsoft has added properties to the DateTime object (Like Is UTC) that makes every thing more complicated and can lead to errors.UtcNow will set property.Your tests should not be needed to see if A > B if conventions are followed.

Comment: It's not opinion-based. This is objectively a ***bad*** idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The local clock on a PC is not that accurate. Its entirely possible that comparing two timestamps between systems will result in incorrect results. Instead have the database apply the timestamp from its own server as it writes the record.

Comment: Thanks, that what I thought too and yes I will move to storing the server timestamp.